# Spring Boot - Handling static resources that are not found (404) and being able to identify the cause of the exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application (`2.3.1.RELEASE`), I serve static resources using:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/favicon.ico").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/favicon.ico");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

This works great. But I'm unable to properly manage a static resource *that is not found*. I want a custom handler to be called when this occures.

My current strategy, in my application, is to manage *all* the exceptions in a single method. Here is what I currently do:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public ErrorResponse handleError(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // Get access to the actual Exception
        Throwable ex = this.errorAttributes.getError(webRequest);

        // Check if it is a 404 exception
        if (ex != null && instanceof NoHandlerFoundException) {
            // Manage the error as a 404!
            // ...
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("generalError", "An error occured");
            return errorResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

This works well, except in one case: when a *static* resource is not found! Spring then calls the `handleError` method because of `@RequestMapping("/error")` but, in that case, the exception returned by `this.errorAttributes.getError(webRequest)` is `null`! So I'm unable to know that it is actually a *404*, and my code therefore returns a general 500 error.

How can I handle the request to an non existing static resource and be able to identify the cause so I can return a 404 instead of a 500?

**EDIT**:

I use those configurations in `application.properties`:

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Configures a request handler for serving static resources by forwarding the request to the Servlet container's "default" Servlet. [DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.html)

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/favicon.ico").addResourceLocations("/static/favicon.ico");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/resources/static/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/error").setViewName("forward:/resources/error/404.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
   }
}
```

Or using ControllerAdvice.

```
@Slf4j
@Order(ORDER)
@RestControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class GlobalRestControllerAdvice {

    public static final int ORDER = 0;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public Map<String, String> handle(NotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        Map<String, String> errorAttributes = new HashMap<>();
        errorAttributes.put("code", "NOT_FOUND");
        errorAttributes.put("message", e.getMessage());
        return errorAttributes;
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Order(GlobalRestControllerAdvice.ORDER + 1)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalHtmlControllerAdvice {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public String handle(NotFoundException e, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        model.addAttribute("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        model.addAttribute("error", "NOT_FOUND");
        model.addAttribute("path", request.getRequestURI());
        model.addAttribute("message", e.getMessage());
        return "/error/404";
    }
}
```

And [ErrorAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/error/ErrorAttributes.html) getError() - Returns : the Exception that caused the error or null.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not able to make this work. Also, for`registry.addViewController("/error").setViewName("forward:/resources/error/404.html");`: I do not want to forward any error to a static file, I want any error to reach my `handleError` method.

Comment: Ah..ok, i think you want to use custom error page. the handleError() to display specific error pages for different error types. um.. how about using only @ControllerAdvice?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to make it work, for now, is to hope that only static resources that are not found will make Spring call my `/error` route, and nothing else...

Also, I get the HTTP status to return with `webRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST)`. Yes it's ugly and I'm open to any cleaner solution!!

So I now have something like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class AppErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

    // Manage REST exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ErrorResponse handleError(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // Ok, not null!
        Throwable ex = this.errorAttributes.getError(webRequest);

        response.setStatus(XXXXXX);
        return new ErrorResponse("My REST error");
    }

    // Manage other exceptions (like static resources that
    // do not exist - 404)
    @RequestMapping(AppConstants.ROUTE_ERROR)
    public String errorRoute(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        int status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value();
        Object statusObj = webRequest.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        if (statusObj != null) {
            status = ((Integer)statusObj).intValue();
        }

        response.setStatus(status);
        return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value() + "";
    }

}
```